# Unable to remove namespace from payload

Tags: xml, wso2, xml-namespaces, payload, wso2-micro-integrator

Hi guys I am trying to make a payload in wso2 MI and has written a code so for the below mentioned code:

```
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:chan="http://www.tibco.com/ChangeSubOfferingAPI/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
              <chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
                <Header>
                  <Username>$1</Username>
                </Header>
                <Body>
                  <SerialNo>$2</SerialNo>
                </Body>
              </chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
            </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
       </format>
       <args>
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:userName"/>
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:password"/>
       </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

I am getting this payload:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:chan="http://www.tibco.com/ChangeSubOfferingAPI/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
            <Header xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
                <Username>abcd</Username>
            </Header>
            <Body xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
                <SerialNo>100000000</SerialNo>
            </Body>
        </chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me understand an guide that what to change in payload factory so xmlns is removed from `Header` and `Body` elements? Rather than `<Header xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">` I want it to be `<Header>` only. Same goes for the `Body` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a empty namespace to your payload like `xmlns=""`

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns="" xmlns:chan="http://www.tibco.com/ChangeSubOfferingAPI/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
              <chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
                <Header>
                  <Username>$1</Username>
                </Header>
                <Body>
                  <SerialNo>$2</SerialNo>
                </Body>
              </chan:ChangeSubOfferingRqsAPI>
            </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
       </format>
       <args>
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:userName"/>
         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:password"/>
       </args>
</payloadFactory>
```